# Enable Bluetooth for pjsip voice call in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip, ios-bluetooth

I am making VOIP app and now we required to connect voice calls with Bluetooth.
We tried to connect the call with Bluetooth but not hear anything.

[image]

```
   /* Initialize audio session category and mode */
{
    AVAudioSession *sess = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    pj_bool_t err;



if ([sess respondsToSelector:@selector(setCategory:withOptions:error:)])
{
    err = [sess setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
            withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
            error:nil] != YES;
    } else {
        err = [sess setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
            error:nil] != YES;
    }
if (err) {
        PJ_LOG(3, (THIS_FILE,
               "Warning: failed settting audio session category"));
}

if ([sess respondsToSelector:@selector(setMode:error:)] &&
    [sess setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:nil] != YES)
{
    PJ_LOG(3, (THIS_FILE, "Warning: failed settting audio mode"));
}
}
```

Above code added in *pjmedia-audiodev->coreaudio_dev.m* file.

Also tried below code :-

```
+(void)EnableBluethooth
  {
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
   [audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord 
  error: 
   nil];
  [audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];
  UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
  OSStatus ostatus = AudioSessionSetProperty (

   kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,


   sizeof(allowBluetoothInput), &allowBluetoothInput);

      pjmedia_aud_dev_route route = PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_ROUTE_BLUETOOTH;
  pj_status_t status = 
   pjsua_snd_set_setting(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_ROUTE, &route, 
   PJ_TRUE);
   NSLog(@"statuys is--->%d",status);


     NSLog(@"status = %x", ostatus);



    }
   +(void)DisableBluethooth
  {
      AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
      [audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord 
       error: nil];
       [audioSession setActive: NO error: nil];
     pjmedia_aud_dev_route route = PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_ROUTE_BLUETOOTH;
       pjsua_snd_set_setting(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_ROUTE, &route, 
     PJ_FALSE);


   }
```

Code execute but not able to hear voice using Bluetooth.
If anyone have an idea of enabling Bluetooth for *pjsip* then please give me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code as text, not an image

Comment: Hello Paulw, edited answer. Please check and give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the **AVAudioSessionCategory** and **port**, set the preferredInput as bluetooth port, so the bluetooth will be activated. Please follow the below code and call `switchBluetooth` method.

```
- (AVAudioSessionPortDescription*)builtinAudioDevice
{
    NSArray* builtinRoutes = @[AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic];
    return [self audioDeviceFromTypes:builtinRoutes];
}        
- (AVAudioSessionPortDescription*)bluetoothAudioDevice
    {
        NSArray* bluetoothRoutes = @[AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP, AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothLE, AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP];
        return [self audioDeviceFromTypes:bluetoothRoutes];
    }

    - (AVAudioSessionPortDescription*)audioDeviceFromTypes:(NSArray*)types
    {
        NSArray* routes = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
        for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* route in routes)
        {
            if ([types containsObject:route.portType])
            {
                return route;
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)switchBluetooth:(BOOL)onOrOff
    {
        NSError* audioError = nil;
        BOOL changeResult = NO;
        if (onOrOff == YES)
        {
            AVAudioSessionPortDescription *bluetoothPort = [self bluetoothAudioDevice];
            if (bluetoothPort) {
                changeResult = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:bluetoothPort
                                                                            error:&audioError];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AVAudioSessionPortDescription* builtinPort = [self builtinAudioDevice];
            if (builtinPort) {
                changeResult = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:builtinPort
                                                                            error:&audioError];
            }
        }
        if (audioError) {
            NSLog(@"BluetoothActiveError: %@ suggestion : %@",audioError.localizedDescription,audioError.localizedRecoverySuggestion);
        }
        return changeResult;
    }
```

Comment: thank for the reply but not working your solution with pjsip.

Comment: did you activate the session after these changes. ?             [session setActive:YES error:&error];

Comment: Hello RJV Kumar ,
above solution working but voice not transfer using bluetooth mic means one side voice is working.video play then hear voice in bluetooth device but call using bluetooth then not transfer my voice from another device.
so if you have any solution then please help me.

Comment: Is there any solution found for the same ?